# Try to put video tag in Next.js Error: Hydration failed because the initial UI does not match what was rendered on the server

Tags: reactjs, next.js

Unhandled Runtime Error
Error: Hydration failed because the initial UI does not match what was rendered on the server.

Warning: Expected server HTML to contain a matching  in .

See more info here: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/react-hydration-error

Component Stack
video
div
Home
App
Call Stack
throwOnHydrationMismatch

```
    import Video from "../src/video.mp4"

    export default function Home() {
      return (
        <div>
        <video src={Video}/>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is your case but for me it was a browser extension I had that controls video player speeds. In the [Next.js docs](https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/react-hydration-error) about the React hydration error, it mentions browser extensions modifying the HTML among other potential causes along with a few potential fixes.

Answer (score -1):

You must use video tag with source

```
<div>
  <video autoPlay loop style={{ width: "500px", height: "500px" }}>
    <source src="/video.mp4" />
  </video>
</div>
```